# pages indexing in google crawl error

Tags: indexing, permalinks, web-crawler, google-search-console

i want to remove the pages that i have removed from the server from google 
or redirect them 
the pages that i have removed from the server are

> www.mysite.com/id?=9898

and

```
www.mysite.com/pagename.html
```

the new pages are

```
www.mysite.com/pagename
```

so i **removed the sitemap** from google and **created a new one and uploaded it**

my problem now is google give me crawl error because of the removed pages like www.sitename.com/contact.html  and the

> indexed page now are only 2 pages

why he can't see that i have removed this pages and when i search on google the removed pages still appears

Answer (score 0):

Better then uploading a new sitemap, is to redirect from your old pages to your new ones. Here you can geht informations about a [301 redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301). 
Your problem is, that Google in fact can not know that the pages www.blabalbal.com/id?234234 and www.blabalbal.com/speaking_url are the same page. So you have to tell Google. A good method is the redirect from above.
You should fix this, because Google maybe crawls both webpages as unique ones and comes to the conclusion that this two pages are duplicate content, which is a bad thing for your rankings.

Comment: i have already deleted it so i wish if you could help me to redirct hese pages

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Disavow Tool - Google to get this done completely.On google search for Disavow Tool - Google and you will get the first link ,login to this by google ID and follow the instructions.USe the same google ID through which sitemap was upload in google webmaster